# how can i fix this error. i am not able to build my docker file

Tags: docker, devops

Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
ashwani@Ashwani:/mnt/c/Users/ashwani/OneDrive/Documents/Desktop/projects/BMI Calculator$

i am expecting a way to fix this and build my image

Comment: Please show your dockerfile. It's not obvious what is your problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.